# How to automatically sync external drive to cloud storage?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sync, cloud-storage

Im looking for a cloud storage service that will allow me to store my computer files (Macbook) as well as everything in my external hard drive.  I prefer for the files to be adding automatically without me having to drag-drop/select every file I need to store. Does anyone know any services that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: Services like Crashplan and Carbonite work well for something like this.

Comment: This sort of subjective "recommendation" question tends to be discouraged here.

Answer (score 1):

An auto-hosted solution is [Seafile](http://seafile.com/). I use it to synchronize over 250 Giga Bytes of data. It works seamlessly. You can setup as many "library" you want. A library can be synchronized to any folder on your Macbook / Windows / GNU/Linux (included the folder where is mounted your external drive). A little warning though: the initial synchronization can take a long time.

I've written a installation guide in french for setting up Seafile with encryption and MySQL database: [Installer Seafile sur Debian](https://howto.biapy.com/fr/debian-gnu-linux/applications-web/gestion-de-fichiers/installer-seafile-sur-debian).

The best known commercial alternative is using [DropBox](http://dropbox.com/), but it can be pricey.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Box.com is having an introductory 50GB free storage. Download the desktop client and point its directory to your external drive. This will sync everything in that drive to the cloud.  From there, you can access it from your iPad, another computer, or anything, also, it will stay up to date as you change or add files.