# Can a FlashDrive auto sync with my Cloud storage?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, cloud-storage

I want my flashdrive to automatically sync and upload all its data to my cloud storage when plugged into my computer (with internet). Is this possible? If so, what existing software can I use?

Comment: You may consider using [DropboxPortableAHK](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjo4ODQ5ejGAhWHnpQKHTGdAJ4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnionsoftware.com%2Fdbpahk%2F&ei=kG6sVejYLYe90gSxuoLwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHEgCNLHsElP3xSE7-9_Fo0ESNmMg&sig2=nknfVD1n_hcHcn5o6OI9UA) to carry the dropbox and configuration file in you flashdrive

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows) I satisfied similar requirements by using PowerShell in combination with a scheduled task.

1. Identify the WMI event that best relates to a USB drive being connected.
2. Create a scheduled task that will run a PowerShell script file when the event is fired.
3. In your script verify the device is actually attached and recover the path.
4. Identify the files to upload.
5. Upload the file using the respective services API.

It would be possible to provide more information if your question stated your operating system, which cloud service you intend to use, any rules used to select files, and how to handle conflicts - but given the nature of the question I have assumed you are only after a general approach to solve the problem. The following resources may help with specifics.

- [Autosync with Scheduled Task](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/task-scheduler-how-to-automatically-synchronize-my/45a49d83-b1d8-4d37-8896-3d2696cf9795?auth=1)
- [Identifying the WMI Event](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/13/hey-scripting-guy-april-13-2010.aspx)
- [Similar Question](https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device)
- [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)
- [Windows Live Services (One Drive) with Powershell](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/07/using-the-windows-live-apis-from-powershell/)

Comment: Hmm yeah I forgot to mention Windows. Are there any prewritten apps or scripts designed to do this task?

Comment: Questions of this nature aren't encouraged here. There is a couple of recommendations in this similar question. http://superuser.com/questions/707737/how-to-automatically-sync-external-drive-to-cloud-storage?rq=1